# combine mysql insert with independent WHERE statement

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a simple INSERT statement which collects data from a simple html form and another mysql table and inserts all the data into a second mysql table.

```
mysqli_query($GLOBALS["conn"], 
    "INSERT INTO `Table2` 
    (idFI, NameSZ, ColorSZ, TimeSZ, RoomSZ, DateSZ) 
    SELECT id, FName, ColorFI, '$Time', '$Room', '$Date' 
    FROM Table1 
    WHERE id = '$FNameid'")
```

This works fine so far.

Now I want to add a statement which inserts a value (1, 2 or 3) into Table2 (RowSZ) depending on the time which was inserted in the input field for TimeSZ.

The rules:

- below 8:00:00 --> Value 1
- between 8:15:00 and 16:00:00 --> Value 2
- above 16:15:00 --> Value 3

Example:

I type the time 12:00:00 into the input field (TimeSZ). When I click the submit button I want, together with the rest of the INSERT INTO statement, that it writes the value 2 into the row (RowSZ)

```
+------+--------+---------+----------+--------+------------+-------+
| idFi | NameSZ | ColorSZ | TimeSZ   | RoomSZ | DateSZ     | RowSZ |
+------+--------+---------+----------+--------+------------+-------+
| 33   | Namexx | #FFFFFF | 12:00:00 | 2      | 2018-06-30 | 2     |
```

The value 2 in RowSZ should be inserted automatically depending on the TimeSZ which was typed into the input field of the form.

How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  You have a working `INSERT` statement, and you're asking how to write another `INSERT` statement?  Have you tried writing another one?  What didn't work?

Comment: I can write another INSERT statement, yes. But I need all the values in the same line row in the mysql table.

Comment: So you want it all to be a single `INSERT` statement?  What's stopping you from using the values you want in that statement?  It's still not clear what you're really asking.

Comment: Well I try to add some details...

Comment: Nick, don't put that in a comment, edit your question and add the expected result there.

Comment: So, column RowSZ will contain 1,2, or 3 depending on the value in TimeSZ in table Table2?

Comment: Shouldn't be too difficult to solve that in PHP: `if ($Time <= '08:00:00') { $RowSZ = 1 } elseif ($Time <= '16:00:00') { $RowSZ = 2 } else { $RowSZ = 3 }`

Comment: @NIck: It sounds like you're just asking how to write an `if` statement in PHP.  Where is your PHP code?  Have you tried anything at all here?  You seem to understand the basic logic of what you want to do.  "If variable X is less than value Y then set another variable to Z", basically.  Have you tried *expressing that logic in code*?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I wasn't sure how to do it in the INSER INTO statement. The answer below solved exactly my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in your SQL Insert statement. In your insert, you can calculate the value for RowSZ based on the time value:

```
INSERT INTO `Table2` 
    (idFI, NameSZ, ColorSZ, TimeSZ, RoomSZ, DateSZ, RowSZ) 
    SELECT id, FName, ColorFI, '$Time', '$Room', '$Date', IF('$time' < '08:00:00',1,if('$time' < '15:00:00',2,3))
    FROM Table1 
    WHERE id = '$FNameid'
```

Comment: I was looking for something like this, but sadly your solution doesn't work. It inserts always value 3.

Comment: You may have to convert the $time value into a date-time or timestamp value for the comparison. I suspect that the comparisons may not work depending upon the formatting of the $time value.

Comment: If your time values before 10:00:00 use a single digit for the hour, you'll need to add a leading zero.

Comment: Perfect! That's it. Thank you!